# add members to administrator with powershell to local network computer

Tags: powershell

`Add-LocalGroupMember  -Group 'Administrators' -Member  'App MDIP National Support'`
I need to be able to add this to a local network computer

Comment: What is `App MDIP National Support`? A group? Are you running this while logged on to that computer as one of the admins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example from the PowerShell documentation,

The new members include a local user account, a Microsoft account, an Azure Active Directory account, and a domain group.

Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member "Admin02", "MicrosoftAccount\username@Outlook.com", "AzureAD\DavidChew@contoso.com", "CONTOSO\Domain Admins"

More information at,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/add-localgroupmember?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).